# que me muestre de forma dinámica los divisores dentro de un select que se agreguen en un input - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo un select que me muestra los divisores de 20 de forma fija, lo que necesito es que si agrego un valor en un input dinámicamente  me salga en el select los divisores para seleccionar, por ejemplo si agrego en el input el valor de 20 en el select me debe aparecer de forma dinámica  para seleccionar 1, 2, 5, 10, 20 que serian los divisores de 20.

```js
function pruebas() {
    return (
        <div>

  <input type="number" placeholder=" Ingresa el divisor de" />
   <br/>          

<select name="tipo_cancha" class="form-control" >
<option value='no' selected>Divisor de 20</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  
</select> 
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default pruebas
```

Comment: Y tu código JavaScript?

Comment: ese es el código que tengo en reactjs y no encuentro como crear lo que comente..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es controlar el valor ingresado en el *input*, y mediante ese valor, obtener el **[mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)** de tu número siempre y cuando el *residuo sea cero*, o lo equivalente, que la división sea exacta.

```
export default function App() {
   const [input, setInput] = useState()
   const [values, setValues] = useState([])

   const getMods = number => {
      let aux = []
      for (let x = 1; x <= number; x++) {
         if (number % x === 0) {
            aux.push(x)
         }
      }
      return aux
   }

   const handleClick = () => {
      if (+input > 0) {
         const mods = getMods(+input)
         setValues(mods)
      }
      setInput('')
   }

   return (
      <>
         <input placeholder='Ingrese divisor' value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
         <button onClick={handleClick}>Agregar divisor</button>
         <hr />
         <br />
         <select name='tipo_cancha' class='form-control'>
            <option value='no' selected>
                Divisor de 20
            </option>
            {values.map((item, index) => (
               <option key={index} value={item}>
                  {item}
               </option>
            ))}
         </select>
      </>
 )}
```

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/agregar-opciones-a-select-mediante-input-991m2?file=/src/App.js)** te dejo el ejemplo completo para que lo revises y pruebes.

Nos comentas si te sirvió o si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: no esta funcionando como lo necesito, osea por ejemplo cuando ingrese un valor en  el input por ejemplo 20 en el select me debe de cargar todos los divisores de 20 que serian 20,10,5,4,2,1 .

Comment: Si me puedes colaborar te encargo la verdad no he podido..

Comment: @Giovanny editada!

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio, pero tengo una ultima duda por ejemplo si no quiero que el numero de coloco en el input no muestre que es divisor por si mismo por ejemplo: divisor de 20 es : 20,10,5,4,2,1 y no quiero que aparezca el 20 en el select como seria ?

Comment: Simplemente, cambia `const mods = getMods(+input).filter(x => x !== +input)` y listo! Recuerda que si la respuesta fue óptima, marcarla como correcta ;)

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio, tengo un ejercicio muy similiar a la pregunta que formule y me gustaria que me ayudaras si es posible https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479369/al-escribir-dentro-de-un-input-un-valor-num%c3%a9rico-x-quiero-que-me-aparezca-en-un

Comment: Antes, veo que has hecho varias preguntas en es.SO pero, aun cuando te han dado respuestas que te sirven, no las has marcado como correctas. Si no sabes como hacerlo, puedes tomar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aclarar tus dudas. Revisaré tu nueva publicación y te comento que tal :D

Comment: listo ya la califique como aceptada , me sirvió bastante, tengo una situación similar a esta si me puede ayudar, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479369/al-escribir-dentro-de-un-input-un-valor-num%c3%a9rico-x-quiero-que-me-aparezca-en-un