# Al escribir dentro de un input un valor numérico x quiero que me aparezca en un select el mismo numero del input pero -1 reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

He logrado que al colocar un numero en el input este se reste -1 y se multiplique dos veces  en el select pero necesito que cada resultado me aparezca por separado en cada "option" en el select y no todo en un mismo "option" y que cada vez que le de clic en el boton agregar aparezca solo los nuevos datos en el select y no que se vayan acomulando como lo esta haciendo

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import './styles.css'

export default function App() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState()
    const [values, setValues] = useState([])

    const handleClick = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setValues([+input, ...values])
        setInput('')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input placeholder='Ingrese divisor' value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Ingrese un numero</button>
            <hr />
            <br />
            <select name='tipo_cancha' class='form-control'>
                <option value='no' selected>
                    Seleccione
                </option>
                {values.map((item, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={item}>
                        {item - 1} {(item -1) * 2}, {(item -1) * 2 * 2}
                    </option>
                    
                    
                ))}
            </select>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Pero estas incluyendo el mismo código de [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479148/que-me-muestre-de-forma-din%c3%a1mica-los-divisores-dentro-de-un-select-que-se-agregu/479154?noredirect=1#comment853459_479154). Has tratado por tu cuenta realizarlo? Ya que con la respuesta que te di en la otra pregunta, debería ser suficiente para que lo puedas resolver por ti mismo. Al final de cuentas, sería solo obtener el valor del input y multiplicarlo, para luego asignárselo al state de tu componente.

Comment: si he intentado realizarlo no lo he logrado, si pudieras colaborarme ya con ese ejemplo trabajaría para futuros casos.

Comment: Añade lo que has intentado a la pregunta, y te vamos orientando en lo que se puede mejorar y/o corregir =D

Comment: listo ya subi lo que logre hacer para que me colabores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estabas casi! Sólo traslada las operaciones que estas realizando dentro de `map`, al método *handleClick*.

```
setValues([(+input - 1), ((+input - 1) * 2), ((+input - 1) * 2 * 2)])
```

Y luego imprime el option como lo harías normalmente

```
{values.map((item, index) => (
   <option key={index} value={item}>
      {item}
   </option>                 
))}
```

Comment: Tengo un inconveniente cuando se envia el valor al select se esta desapareciendo el valor que coloque en el input y necesito que el valor en el input no se borre cuando le doy en el boton.

Comment: Comenta setInput('') y listo

Comment: hola amigo tengo otro inconveniente  y genere una nueva pregunta , adicione el código que llevo , te agradezco que me puedas ayudar .  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/480089/tengo-errores-al-generar-select-din%c3%a1micos-reactjs

Comment: te encargo si me puedes ayudar en lo que puedas , te lo agradecería.

Comment: hola amigo te encargo si me puedes ayudar ..